# Built-in mechanisms to fetch the corresponding source code for AGPLv3-licensed projects

Tags: agpl-3.0, source-code

In the AGPLv3 text -after the `END OF TERMS AND CONDITIONS` line- there is this recommendation on [How to Apply These Terms to Your New Programs](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/agpl-3.0#howto) which rather terse and states that there are `many ways` to offer source code:

> [...] *If your software can interact with users remotely through a computer network, you should also make sure that it provides a way for users to get its source. For example, if your program is a web application, its interface could display a "Source" link that leads users to an archive of the code. There are many ways you could offer source, and different solutions will be better for different programs; see section 13 for the specific requirements.* [...]

And the section 13 it points back to does not provide much more guidance:

> [...] *through some standard or customary means of facilitating copying of software.*

So what are actual mechanisms implemented by AGPL-licensed projects for users to get the corresponding source code?

- for a web application with a UI?
- for an application with no UI and only a REST API?
- for a command line application?
- for a library?

Comment: Isn't the question rather how to "prominently offer all users interacting with it [the software] remotely through a computer network (if your version supports such interaction) an opportunity to receive the Corresponding Source" and not so much about the actual mechanism used to eventually obtain the source? A link to a downloadable archive would work in all cases, but an issue is where such a link would be displayed if there is no user interaction.

Comment: @MansGunnarsson: yes, you are right: where would this link be displayed? and what would be examples?